# Laravel Apache2 : You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, permissions, apache2

I created a new folder in public/ (in a laravel porject running on apache2) I set the permissions to 777 but apache keep having this error when I try to acceed to the folder with my browser : "You don't have permission to access this resource."

I'm using ubuntu for the OS. Here is my apache configuration file :

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin contact@wewatch.fr
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/public/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Since you tagged this Laravel you need to check whether all the .php files are also accessible by apache not just the folder

Comment: There are image in that folder, in my code the images are load but when I try to watch them directly from the url, error 403 forbiddent.